# Перевод с MS SQL на mysql через Migration Wizard

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Использую  Migration Wizard  в Workbench что бы перенести БД на mysql.Настройки для Source Selection :

> Database System = Microsoft SQL SERVER
>
> Connectiton Method = ODBC (native)

Test Connection проходит успешно. Настройки для Target Selection :

> Stored Connection : Local instanse Mysql57
> Connectiton Method : Standart TCP/IP

Test Connection также проходит успешно. Жму далее и процесс фризится на Feth Shemas List и ничего не происходит. В чем может быть проблема ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не уверен, что здесь найдутся специалисты по конкретному не очень известному инструменту. Я бы рекомендовал обратиться на форум поддержки этого инструмента, если такой существует, или в службу поддержки. 
Причины же предположить можно, но без понимания инструмента это будет чисто гадание. Это такие варианты, как слишком сложная схема, неподдерживаемые типы объектов базы, ошибка самой программы и т.п.

Comment: @minamoto Использовал мастер сценариев MS SQL, все заработало.